# Pandas if else condition on a timestamp type

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

the date column is a timestamp. I am looking to write a if-else condition to manipulate sold to 0 if the date is less than '2021-01-15' and keep as is if the date is greater than or equal to '2021-01-15'.
but I keep getting this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'Timestamp'

```
   date        sold
2021-01-01      20
2021-01-02      21
2021-01-03      25
2021-01-04      22
2021-01-05      29
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: tried a couple things:  for i, rows in df.iterrows():
    rows['updated_sold']= rows['sold'] if rows['stay_date'] >='2021-15-01' else 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.loc[df['date'] < '2021-01-15', 'sold'] = 0
```